# Localhost not connecting to mongodb after deploying to Heroku

Tags: database, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I was running off localhost fine with mongodb and then switched to mLab and that was fine too, but now trying to run the database off localhost again I get a 422 error when it tries to connect.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/wines 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

I deployed this site once before and was able to switch back and forth so not sure what is wrong.

This is my server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes");

// Connect to the Mongo DB

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/wineDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });

// require("./models/wine");

// Define middleware here
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
// Add routes, both API and view
app.use(routes);

// Define API routes here

// Send every other request to the React app
// Define any API routes before this runs
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

I'm wondering if somehow my code is trying to do production mode that is needed to connect to mlab and no longer allowing me to connect to DB through localhost?

Comment: `I'm wondering if somehow my code is trying to do production mode that is needed to connect to mlab and no longer allowing me to connect to DB through localhost?` Perhaps. You could add some `console.log`s to see which database you are using. Also, is your local mongoDB working - perhaps something happened to it. Lastly, if you switch back to mLab, does that still work?

Comment: In addition to what davejagoda said, it looks like error above is an HTTP request error / status code. Did your app log any other messages / errors?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was wrong about the source. It was because I had port 3001 running somewhere in the background so when I killed it that fixed the problem!